# How to get rid of this ajax form posting issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am posting a form to controller action. I am getting an error from the controller.

This is the behavior I want:
If error - show the right error message on the same page without any page refresh.
If success - show the success message on the page again no page refresh

what I am getting is that the page gets fully refreshed with different url and shows this:
{"status":"Failed","msg":"\u0027Name\u0027 "}

The url changes to this: ../respond/update which is the action I post to

Basically I want to catch this Failed status and display the msg inside a span.

But why it is taking me to a different page?

Here is the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Respond", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmUpdate" }))
{
  //have my form here
  //submit button
}

Here is the js handler that posts the form:
$('#frmUpdate').submit(function () {
            //validation
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend: //show loader
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.status);                    
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) { alert('error'); }
            });
            return false;
        });

Here is controller:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(ResponseModel model)
{
    return Json(new { status="Failed", msg = "Name" });
}
```

**EDIT:**
In Firefox it takes to differnt url.
But in IE8 I get this error from jquery itself. Interesting...

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 28
Char: 12724
Code: 0
URI: /Content/js/external/jquery-1.6.2.min.js?v=3

Comment: Are you seeing some javascript errors in your console? What's in the beforeSend callback? What you have shown in your question is invalid javascript because you haven't completed the beforeSend callback.

Comment: Also I notice some `\u0027` in your JSON. They shouldn't be present if your controller action looks as what you have shown here.

Comment: I updated the question with js error in IE8. I removed all code from controller for clarity. Also beforesend is fine. I just show a loader that it is being processed.

Comment: in FireFox what error are you getting in the console?

Comment: No error in FF console. I just a {"status":"Failed","msg":" \u0027kids\u0027 "} on a white page

Comment: OK. Darrin, if (d.beforeSend && (d.beforeSend.call(e, v, d) === !1 || s === 2))  this is the line jquery plugin that giving error. But why?

Comment: because you probably have an error in your beforeSend method.

Comment: OK. Fixed it. But Darrin, you are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should stop the default submit behavior by doing so:

```
$('#frmUpdate').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  <your code here>
});
```

Otherwise the form submit will happen causing the behaviour you want to avoid.
Hope this helps.

Comment: He returns false from the submit handler which should cancel the default action.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Respond", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmUpdate" }))
{
  //have my form here
  //submit button 
}
```

If you are using submit button than it will post the page. You need to use type button instead of submit.

It will work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Respond", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmUpdate" }))
{
  //have my form here
  //use type button 
}
```

Comment: The submit handler that the OP subscribed to will never be invoked if he uses a type button instead of submit button.

Comment: @Darin ... But we can call javascript function on its click event and if it is satisfying all the condition than we can submit that form else return false.....


function ValidateUser() {
var isReturn = false;

if (isReturn) {
                $("#userfrm").submit();
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
}